# Getting overall commits Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm building a panel to show users there github statistics as well as some other data all on one page.

I'm looking at trying to fetch a count of a users commits not specific to any repository but an overall count. All the methods I've found on the API seem to only return counts to a specific repository.

Has anyone manged to obtain this data?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
https://api.github.com/users/{username}/events
```

So if the username you are interested in obtaining information for is Paradigm, your request would be:

```
https://api.github.com/users/paradigm/events
```

The JSON object that is returned has a type. The type you are interested in has a value of "PushEvent".

To obtain, all of their commits, you must know their Api limits to 100 results per request(and has some other limits, such as 60 unauthenticated requests per hour). So depending on how programmatically you are doing this, you would want to make your requests as follows:

```
https://api.github.com/users/paradigm/events?page=1&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/users/paradigm/events?page=2&per_page=100
etc...
```